# C# Creating a list for events that did not occur today

Tags: c#

I`m making an application for an animal shelter, and each time a dog is added to the animal list it has to have the date it last went for a walk. Part of the assignment is to show a list of dogs that are not walked out TODAY. Any ideas?

Comment: The question is not answerable by now.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Konstantin.  Questions here get a LOT more traction when you have done the following:  1. Posted your code 2. Shown us what you have tried and 3. Don't ask us to _do your work for you_.  Please consider posting your code; in spite of having 2 answers below.

Comment: Today? midnight? dawn? opening time? UTC? Dog-time? ;) Persistent list (like a database, and most likely needed) or an in-memory structure? Not a well-formed, or well-research question. It could be improved to one; (see Brian's comment)

Answer (score 2):

OK, assuming that you have a "LastWalked" column in your data structure you want something like:

```
var dogsNotWalked = allDogs.Where(d => d.LastWalked < DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: Great minds think alike B^)

Comment: You have to assume too much, answers are just guesses.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I think assuming there's a "LastWalked" column is a fair assumption.

Comment: @ChrisF: The main assumption is that OP doesn't know `DateTime.Today`. That's hypothetical.

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you'd try something before asking for help. Not to mention showing your work. It's not exactly difficult, a one-liner, in fact. Try something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Dog> Dogs { get ; set ; }

public IEnumerable<Dog> FindDogsNotWalkedRecently( DateTime referenceDate )
{
    return Dogs.Where( dog => dog.LastWalkedAt < referenceDate ) ;
}
```